# How do I check the colour of a pixel?

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyscreeze

Posting because the posts where this has been fixed are dead and the people maintaining the code haven't replied in months.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Combined_180222_desktop_version .py", line 510, in <module>
    detection()
  File "c:\Users\Combined_180222_desktop_version .py", line 464, in detection
    r,g,b = py.pixel(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 614, in pixel
    return (r, g, b)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 123, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

I'm just trying to check the `rgb` value of a pixel.

```
import pyautogui as py

x, y = 1742, 979
r, g, b = py.pixel(x, y)

if b == 106:
    do_something()
```

When this stopped working I swapped to `try` and `except` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146513/pyautogui-and-pyscreeze-crash-with-windll-user32-releasedc-failed) which worked for about two months but now the error is back.

```
import pyautogui as py

x, y = 1742, 979
r, g, b = py.pixel(x, y)
        
try:
    if b == 106:
        do_something()
except:
    if b == 106:
        do_somethinge()
```

- [i got a windows error and os error while making a pyautogui program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359699/i-got-a-windows-error-and-os-error-while-making-a-pyautogui-program)
- [Python windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700237/python-windll-user32-releasedc-failed-error)
- ["windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0" from pyautogui.pixel()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64741292/windll-user32-releasedc-failed-return-0-from-pyautogui-pixel)
- [Python PyAutoGui pixelMatchesColor raises windll.user32.ReleaseDC Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708880/python-pyautogui-pixelmatchescolor-raises-windll-user32-releasedc-error)
- [Pyautogui and pyscreeze crash with windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146513/pyautogui-and-pyscreeze-crash-with-windll-user32-releasedc-failed)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pythonhelp/comments/idwggk/raise_windowserrorwindlluser32releasedc_failed/

I could link another half dozen posts all around the same error. There's a lot of information [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/579) about the route of the issue being `pixel` and `pyscreeze` being the route of the issue and in this stack [Pyautogui and pyscreeze crash with windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146513/pyautogui-and-pyscreeze-crash-with-windll-user32-releasedc-failed) one of the `pyscreeze` maintainers claims it was fixed back in `0.1.28` yet it's not fixed and I can't seem to find anyone who's doing anything other than talking about it not being fixed.

`pip show pyscreeze` confirms I'm running `0.1.28` which is meant to contain the fix. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

It might be relevant so I'm posting this next section anyway but may remove it if not relevant to the answer. I am using `windll.user32.ReleaseDC` elsewhere in a separate class:

```
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con

class WindowCapture:

    # properties
    w = 0
    h = 0
    hwnd = None
    cropped_x = 0
    cropped_y = 0
    offset_x = 0
    offset_y = 0

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, window_name=None):
        # find the handle for the window we want to capture.
        # if no window name is given, capture the entire screen
        if window_name is None:
            self.hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        else:
            self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
            if not self.hwnd:
                raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

        # get the window size
        window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
        self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
        self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

        # account for the window border and titlebar and cut them off
        border_pixels = 0
        titlebar_pixels = 0
        self.w = self.w - (border_pixels * 2)
        self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
        self.cropped_x = border_pixels
        self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

        # set the cropped coordinates offset so we can translate screenshot
        # images into actual screen positions
        self.offset_x = window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
        self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

    def get_haystack(self):

        # get the window image data
        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
        dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
        # dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
        signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

        # free resources
        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
        img = img[...,:3]
        img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)
        return img

    @staticmethod
    def list_window_names():
        def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
        win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

    # translate a pixel position on a screenshot image to a pixel position on the screen.
    # pos = (x, y)
    def get_screen_position(self, pos):
        return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y)
```

Comment: That code simply tries twice. You can try trying 3 or more times in a loop and maybe it will work eventually

Comment: @mousetail I never thought to try just adding more lol, you don't think something else could be at play? It's actually a really good point because one of the links the test case shows it failing randomly. I wonder if there's a way to do *try until succedes*

Comment: A `try`/`except` has to enclose the line that actually throws the error - which is the call to `py.pixel()`, *not* the comparison `b == 106`.